# MSDTC Errors: QueryInterface failed for "ITransactionDispenser": 0x8004d01c(XACT_E_CONNECTION_DOWN)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql-server-2012, msdtc

I’m having some issues with a server where MSDTC is not working properly.  This started happening about two days ago.  I’ve tried a number of different things including restarting the VM [and I’ve tried the fix found on this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/01/18/how-to-troubleshoot-the-red-arrow-issue-in-component-services-ii.aspx).

However, none of this has resolved the issue.  My Computer in dcomcnfg shows red down arrow and the SQL Server log file has errors below repeatedly:

> Attempting to initialize Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> QueryInterface failed for "ITransactionDispenser": 0x8004d01c(XACT_E_CONNECTION_DOWN).

Comment: Is there anything in the system or application error log around the time when you're getting the connection errors? How about when you bounce the DTC service?

Comment: @BenThul Only the message above and I've tried restarting the DTC Service as well as restarting the server.